# How to protect Google spreadsheet all sheets option?

Tags: google-sheets, protected

I have build an online Google spreadsheet. That spreadsheet accessed 6 person everyday.

I made 5 sheets in my spreadsheet `Meals`, `Marketing`, `Contribution`, `Cakculator` and `Notes`

I want to protect these sheet from other user. I gave limited area to protect my data. I have done that. But unable to protect my sheet options.

See screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Delete, Hide, Rename, Duplicate, Copy to.. options should access only owner who is created this spreadsheet. Can you Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Not a programming question. See [webapps.se].

Answer (score 0):

As you are the owner the options will always appear for you. If you set the protections and share the file then open it with another account or sing out and open it and you should see the protections are in place.